# TextInputEditText in android not getting focus

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

i have a spinner and 2 TextInputEditText inside a linear layout.

inside a fragment i added this layout to the popup window.
for spinner i added a custom adapter with image and text.
the TextInputEditText are not getting focus, i tried all the possible ways.

tried with below possible conditions

```
m_PopupWindow.Focusable = true;
 m_PopupWindow.SoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateVisible;
 m_PopupWindow.OutsideTouchable=(true);
 m_PopupWindow.Touchable=(true);
 m_PopupWindow.Update();
```

and also tried getting the keypad to focus with TextInputEditText click event, with this able to open the keypad but the TextInputEditText is not getting the focus.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/popupBorder"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

         <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="328dp"
          android:minWidth="15dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="328dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="328dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable ="true"
                android:focusable="true"
            android:imeActionLabel="Done"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="328dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTintMode="src_atop"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@drawable/selector_password_visibility_toggle"
                app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ibk_visible"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
            android:layout_width="328dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeActionLabel="Done"
            android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>




View objPopupview = LayoutInflater.From(ViewGroup.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.AddAccountTabPage, null);
            m_PopupWindow = new PopupWindow(objPopupview, LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent, true);
            m_PopupWindow.Focusable = true;
             m_PopupWindow.SoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateVisible;
            m_PopupWindow.OutsideTouchable=(true);
            m_PopupWindow.Touchable=(true);
            m_PopupWindow.Update();

 txtUserNameEditBox.Click += delegate
                {
                    txtUserNameEditBox.RequestFocus();
                    txtUserName.RequestFocus();
                    txtUserName.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)ViewGroup.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.ShowSoftInput(txtUserName, ShowFlags.Forced);
                    imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a couple of things wrong.

Remove the following attributes from `parent LinearLayout`

```
// remove this from parent layouts
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

> You only use `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on parent ViewGroup so that its
>   contents are read all at once for **screen reader** users making use of `keyboard navigation`, `remote control` or `trackball` which would require the view to be first selected, then follows and extra action like click an OK to trigger action/focus events.

...

> Focusable in touch mode is a property that should be used sparingly and only in
>   very specific situations as it breaks consistency with normal Android
>   behavior.

Unless you expect the above stated behaviour, that line is unnecessary.

Secondly, remove the following attributes from `parent LinearLayout`. This i guess may be the culprit of your major challenge:

```
// remove this from parent layouts
android:clickable="true"
```

When a view parent is `clickable *OR* (focusable *AND* focusableInTouchMode)` its onTouch event intercepts that of its children which can cause unexpected behavior preventing the children from being clickable.

Also comment out the following line:

```
// comment this out
m_PopupWindow.Touchable=(true);
m_PopupWindow.Focusable = true;
```

Further more you can call immediate `request focus` on your EditText by adding `<requestFocus />` tag in xml

```
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Hi @GiddyNaya thanks for your response,   i tried with the suggestions mentioned above, with setting up the  <requestFocus /> tag the edit text getting the focus but the text is not getting entered into text box and also if we set the  <requestFocus /> tag for both the Edittext in my layout then both are getting the focus at a time.

Comment: You can only use the `<requestFocus />` tag for just one view in your layout

Comment: Also remove the line `android:textIsSelectable="true"` from your `TextInputEditText`. It is selectable by default

Comment: i tried all the mentioned scenarios, but i think there is some other issue for this as even the edit text got focus not taking the text we are entering.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions guys but unfortunately nothing worked fine, but i just removed the Linear layout and placed entire controls in Table layout and it worked , don't know exact issue but this one resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the following code in your root layout.

```
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Note:
When you set `blocksDescendants` to `android:descendantFocusability` , then the ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.